# Fail to deploy outlook add in to Office 365

Tags: office365, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I am using this sample https://github.com/OfficeDev/outlook-add-in-attachments-demo to deploy to my Azure. I followed the instruction and I could run the project successfully in local PC. However, I failed to upload this sample to my tenant.

The steps I did are as below:

- Deploy the project to azure website.
- In the manifest file, I just replace all tags with ~remoteAppUrl with my new uploaded website URL
     (https://testxxxx.azurewebsites.net)
- Then I go to my Outlook online, select Manage Add ins menu and upload my manifest file. But it failed.
- I tried to reproduce it why it failed, I realized that it failed in Urls/Url tag. If I keep the Urls point to my local PC then
  it
     works. If I point them to azure website URL, it didn't. It shown the error message: The installation is taking longer than expected. If your add-in doesn't appear shortly, try installing it again.

It worked with these lines:

```
<bt:Url id="functionFile" DefaultValue="https://localhost:44349/Functions/FunctionFile.html"/>
<bt:Url id="messageReadTaskPaneUrl" DefaultValue="https://localhost:44349/MessageRead.html"/>
```

and failed when I replaced the URLs

```
<bt:Url id="functionFile" DefaultValue="https://testoladd.azurewebsites.net/Functions/FunctionFile.html"/>
<bt:Url id="messageReadTaskPaneUrl" DefaultValue="https://testoladd.azurewebsites.net/MessageRead.html"/>
```

This is my manifest file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1i_VCNpnxCyvo8uo1p1P5b2oqH4YDIW-o/view

Please advise me in this situation.

[image]

Comment: i have the same issue, How could be??? huhuhu, please help T.T

Comment: Can you also share the error, which you get in store?

Comment: I uploaded it to my organization, not store. The error message is quite general: The installation is taking longer than expected. If your add-in doesn't appear shortly, try installing it again.

Comment: Can you share the manifest?

Comment: It the the same as the manifest the sample. I just replace all tags ~remoteAppUrl with my published URL

Comment: Hi @amzdmt,  Please share the manifest for further investigation.

Comment: Sorry, this my my manifest file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1i_VCNpnxCyvo8uo1p1P5b2oqH4YDIW-o/view

Comment: I found out that if I remove VersionOverridesV1_1, I will be able to upload. However, I dont want to remove because VersionOverridesV1_1 supports SSO

Comment: Thanks for sharing the manifest. The issue is as below
The manifest file doesn't conform to the schema definition.The 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1:Id' element is invalid - The value 'YOUR APP ID HERE' is invalid according to its datatype 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0:UUID' - The Pattern constraint failed.The 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1:Id' element is invalid - The value 'YOUR APP ID HERE' is invalid according to its datatype 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0:UUID'

Comment: Fixing above issue should solve the problem. Let me know you are unblocked after above fix.

Comment: Thanks Harshitkapoor but it is not the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173960/discussion-between-harshitkapoor-and-amzdmt).

Comment: Can you share more details on that. I have modified your manifest as per documentation and is available here https://drive.google.com/file/d/15IYM0mBoG2i29ELoxdWxsumPXke1h5ud/view?usp=sharing

I was able to successfully install it.

Comment: Thanks Harshitkapoor for resolving my issue.